# Optical Mark Recognition in javascript for cross plateform mobile app

Tags: javascript, image-processing, cross-platform, multiple-choice, omr

I'd like to build an exam correction app. From a paper multiple choice question (mcq) I'd like to use my camera to analyse it and get a score.
This exist in python https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/

Does someone know a lib in javascript for this ? 
[image]

Comment: Are you looking to build the algorithm yourself or does it have to be an existing solution? If you are a bit familar with image processing, you could rebuild the algorithm of the article you posted with opencv, as there are opencv bindings available for javascript.

Comment: I don't find openCV for a mobile cross-plateform framework ... (Buildable on Android and iOS)
The solution I found is to use react-native with ar.js... but it's very recent. Maybe not stable

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing. As I found out, you should not use Javascript due to performance reason.
You should do the following steps:

- Write a native module for Android or iOS or C++ for both to handle image
- Write a native module to process frames from camera to get appropriate frame and pass it to the image handling module.
- Bridge all them to React Native side, handle them like other native libraries

Read more about native module: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/native-modules-android

You may need OpenCV library to handle your images

Comment: Check this link to see if it could help:
OpenCV for JS:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html